# How to ignore duplicate value from array using for-each?

Tags: php

How to ignore duplicate value from array using `foreach()` ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sa_uc_id] => 1
            [uc_um_id] => 1
            [ui_coverimage] => 1513351051.jpg
            [um_name] => Suresh Gyan Vihar University
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sa_uc_id] => 2
            [uc_um_id] => 1
            [ui_coverimage] => 1513351051.jpg
            [um_name] => Suresh Gyan Vihar University
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sa_uc_id] => 3
            [uc_um_id] => 1
            [ui_coverimage] => 1513351051.jpg
            [um_name] => Suresh Gyan Vihar University
        )

)
```

Comment: Is it the [ui_coverimage] you do not want duplicate?

Comment: why mysql  tag  ?????????

Comment: That fields are coming from db and i want un_name uniquely

Comment: which value that you want to ignore?

Comment: What is expected outcome you want? What code you have tried? Please elaborate your question more. Add these details in your question by edit it

Comment: 'Suresh Gyan Vihar University' this name i want ignore

Comment: @YogeshJamkar  you have to add your expected outcome in the same way as you posted the inut data. Also your effort what ou tried so far

Comment: @YogeshJamkar  please post your expected outcome. (Add in your question). otherwise you will get lot of incomplete answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for nested array there the `array_uniqe` some time moderate the answer for multi-level because of there the list item `sa_uc_id` is unique.In above you have use array without `sa_uc_id` to use `array_unique`. If above answer not working then try this one...

```
$data_ar = array();//your array here;
$temp_ar = array();

foreach($data_ar as $value)
{
    $tempCheck = 0;
    foreach($temp_ar as $val)
    {
        if($val['uc_um_id'] == $val['uc_um_id']) // whatever the item value you want to check wheather its uc_um_id or um_name
        {
            $tempCheck = 1;
        }
    }
    if($tempCheck === 0)
    $temp_ar[] = $value;
}
var_dump($temp_ar);
```

Comment: if($value['uc_um_id'] == $val['uc_um_id']) // whatever the item value you want to check wheather its uc_um_id or um_name
        {
            $tempCheck = 1;
        }

Comment: @YogeshJamkar  wow, you got the answer.

Comment: Yes  its working fine......Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. No intermediate variables are saved.

We used this to de-duplicate results from a variety of overlapping queries.

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

Comment: this will not work in OP's case. take his input array and check. it's because complete sub-arrays are not identical. only one-or-two indexes of sub-arrays are identical. In this case He will lost usful info or nothing will happen at all

Comment: There you have to mention the ref of your answer if it's copied from somewhere.copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Comment: yeah.. I forgot to mention it.